# Exception when Interating through ListBox.Items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, iteration

If no item is selected in the ListBox, then the code works fine.

If at least one item is selected in the ListBox, the foreach iteration breaks after the first item is evaluated. The exception is an InvalidOperationException and the detail shows Items collection has been modified.

```
foreach (object item in listBoxFiles.Items) //InvalidOperationException occurs
{
    if (listBoxFiles.SelectedItems.Contains(item)) 
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I was looking for something like **ListBoxItem.IsSelected** but it does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure `//do nothing` does nothing to the item collection?

Comment: Yes, in fact after removing all the codes inside the if-clause the error is still reproducible.

Comment: And it also throws if nothing is selected.

Comment: If I select an item and then deselect it, the exception is thrown. If I don't select/unselect any item, the exception will not be thrown. Strange behaviour, I think this is a bug in the WinForm library.

Comment: I created a form with a listbox and a button. The LB gets populated with some items and the click-Handler for the button executes your code above. The interation throws even if I never selected any items.

Comment: Oh , I got it. I the selection mode is "One" then it will throw without any previous selections. If it is e.g. MultiSimple it will only throw if some item gets selected first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem. The access to `SelectedItems` seems to be changing `Items`, not the call to `Contains`. It should not do that. I have no explanation at the moment.

Workaround:

If you check if `item` is contained in `SelectedItems` you could right away iterate over `SelectedItems` instead. Another alternative would be to copy `SelectedItems` before the iteration like this:

```
List<object> selectedItems = new List<object>();
selectedItems.AddRange( listBoxFiles.SelectedItems.OfType<object>() );
```

Comment: No need to make a full copy... you could just create a new reference outside of the iteration:  `ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection selectedItems = listBoxFiles.SelectedItems;`

Comment: @drumboog - new reference does not work. I have to create a full copy (Eric's workaround).

Comment: Yes, a reference would still work on the same collection. (as expected)

Comment: @Robin Maben - A reference does not work. The get-accessor of SelectedItems seems to be doing something odd.

Comment: And that is not an assumption or an opinion, a did actually try it.